# Update Adapter data from an external BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` which is used for different alarms set by the `AlarmManger`. This Receiver will check if an event is fulfilled when it starts (depending on the location).

These events are displayed via a `BaseExpandableListAdapter`. What is the easiest way to update the events in my adapter from the Receiver?
The receiver cannot be an inner class! It is used in different Activities and Fragments!

What I tried was to pass an callback to my Adapter to notify the Activity/Fragment to update the data. `"Events before"` and `"Events after"` are always 0 (I think this is due to the `getInstance()`-method fails somehow).

```
public class EventAdapter(Context context, List<Event> events, EventAdapterCallback callback) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.events = events;
    this.callback = callback;

    instance = this;
}

public static EventAdapter getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

public void requestUpdate() {
    callback.update();
}


public class EventBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        // ... doing my stuff
        // send live update to the adapter
        EventAdapter.getInstance().requestUpdate();
    }
}


public class RandomFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        eventsAdapter = new EventAdapter(getActivity(), events, new EventAdapterCallback() {
            public void update() {
                Log.i("Events before:", String.valueOf(events.size()));
                events.clear();
                events.addAll(database.getList());
                Log.i("Events after:", String.valueOf(events.size()));
                eventsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use observer pattern, make all your adapters implement an interface let's say Updatable, containing an update() method.

Have any manager "singleton" or your app Application class, have a List any in all your activities or fragments that has an adapter that needs to be updated, add that adapter to the list, at the destruction of the activity or fragment, remove the adapter from the list.

when ever you have something you need to update the adapters with, loop over the list and call their update method.

Comment: This seems to work fine. I will need to do some testing and mark your answer later if everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are doing this somewhere in the code. But I could not locate it.

You need to register the broadcast receiver in your fragment.

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance (this);

    localBroadcastManager.registerReceiver (<instance-of-your-broadcast-receiver>, new IntentFilter ("UpdateRandomFragment"));
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver (<instance-of-your-broadcast-receiver>);
}
```

In your onReceive

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals ("UpdateRandomFragment"))
        {
            ((RandomFragment)context).eventAdapter.clear();
            ((RandomFragment)context).eventAdapter.addAll(...);
            ((RandomFragment)context).eventAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Isn't that working the other way around? When `onResume` is called in my Fragment, the `BroadcastReceiver` will be executing these updates? Cause I want in the other way around (`BroadcastReceiver` will notify my Fragment/Activity).

Comment: Are you looking for an alarm to trigger some logic in your app when your app is not in the foreground? Or do you want the update to happen when you resume your app? If it is the former, you may want to look into PendingIntent.

Comment: The UI should be updated if the app is still running (fore- or background) with a `Fragment`/`Activity` which uses the Adapter class ti display events. This updated should be triggered from the `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: I think what I have posted works exactly how you want it. If the app is in the foreground, then the fragment will be ready to receive broadcasts (by means of the onReceive). If it is in the background, you shouldn't have to refresh the list unless the user brings it into the foreground. When the user does bring it into the foreground, refresh the list by explicitly adding items to the adapter. This should be done in the onStart method. Hope this helps.

Comment: I see, you meant to put the `onReceive` method inside my `Fragment`? I thought you meant to put it in my `BroadcastReceiver`. But how to notify the `Fragment` from my `BroadcastReceiver` now?

Comment: If the `onReceive` is inside your `Fragment`, then you should be having an instance of the `Adapter` inside your fragment as well. From the onReceive, reset those values and trigger a notifyDataSetChanged call.

Comment: Could you provide us with some more code example? I think we are talking past each other. Thank you.